# Need some guidance around creating a custom page to display different views for a SharePoint List.

Tags: sharepoint

I'm familiar with SharePoint but would like some guidance on developing a custom page.

I have 1 list and have created 3 different views.

On my Page, I have added a webpart to show the list.

I'd like to be able to add some form items - possibly radio buttons/ a picker/ or just text links at the top that would allow the user to switch views on the list below.

I'd like to add some other information and make the experience more intuitive for the user.

In short, is there a way to add a list web part and some options to choose the view of that list in another section of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just do something like this

```
var dview = MyList.Views["YourViewTitle"];
dview.DefaultView = true;
dview.Update();
MyList.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Each view has its own URL so you just need to use some HTML and JavaScript. When a box is checked or a button is clicked then you can load the URL of the view.